# $A=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2 \\ 4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$ ,find $e^{xA}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

$A=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2 \\ 4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$

I have to find $e^{xA}$ by definition ,

$A^0=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$A^1=\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2 \\ 4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$

$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}33 & 24 \\ 48 & 57\end{pmatrix}$

$A^n$ is not clear to me.

Help please ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: Two possibilities: (1) derive recurrences for the entries of $A^n$, (2nd order). (2) diagonalize the matrix.

Comment: Use the characteristic polynomial of $A$ to show its eigenvalues are $3,\,9$. Find matrices $B,\,C$ with $A^n=3^nB+9^nC$ by solving equations from the cases $n\in\{0,\,1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pursuant to Edgar's comment, you should diagonalize the matrix, i.e. rewrite $A = PDP^{-1}$ and calculate
\begin{align*}
e^{At} :&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(At)^{j}}{j!} \\
&= P \left (\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(Dt)^{j}}{j!} \right )P^{-1} \\
&= P\, \mathrm{diag} \{e^{\lambda_{j} t} \} P^{-1}.
\end{align*}
To do so: first find roots to characteristic equation $\lambda^{2}-12\lambda+27 =  0 \implies \lambda \in \{3,9 \}$ and find eigenvectors $\vec{v_{3}} = (2,-1)^{T}$ and $\vec{v_{9}} = (1,1)^{T}$, whence $P = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Finally, one may calculate $P^{-1}$ and $e^{At} = P \begin{pmatrix} e^{3t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{9t} \end{pmatrix} P^{-1}$ using matrix algebra. I'll leave this as an exercise.